# How to select all the cells in an excel using Java and apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have created an excel sheet and gave it some data. Now i have to select all the cells in the excel sheet, so that i can apply wrapping of text to all of them at once. My data that is stored in the excel sheet is dynamic Can someone help me in this please. I'm using Java and Apache POI.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: selecting cells is something done in excell itself, so, afaik, outside of the jvm. what have you tried so far, and what is it you're having trouble with?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a lack of effort

Answer (score 2):

There is not need to select cells in Apache POI. You should just iterate over them and perform some actions that you want.

Look at this iteration example: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator

In your case it would be something like this:

```
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            cell.getCellStyle().setWrapText(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CellRangeAddress region = new CellRangeAddress(6, 8, 1, 10); //CellRangeAddress(startRow,endRow,startCell,endCell)
RegionUtil.setWrapText(true, region, sheet);
```

or

```
CellRangeAddress region = CellRangeAddress.valueOf(A6:J8); 
RegionUtil.setWrapText(true, region, sheet);
```

[Check this documentation on poi.apache.org](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddress.html)

Comment: RegionUtil does not supported by setWrapText method. Can you suggest something else.